# Selenium call async JavaScript in C#

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automated-tests, blazor

I need to call async JavaScript function at get the function value in Selenium. I tried but I am getting Script timeout error.

My JavaScript Code is

```
async function SnapScreen() {
    var node = document.getElementById("videoContainer");

    var result = await domtoimage.toPng(node);

    console.log(result);

    return result;
}
```

I have tried

```
1) Driver?.ExecuteJavaScript("ScreenToBase64()");
```

```
2) IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var obj = js.ExecuteAsyncScript(script, args);
```

I am getting Script Timeout and never ge the value back.

```
3) var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
var data = wait.Until(driver => driver.ExecuteJavaScript<T>(script, args));
```

```
4) var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
var data = wait.Until(driver => js.ExecuteAsyncScript(script, args));
```

and my Driver and EdgeOptions are

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);

var edgeDriverService = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

edgeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions { PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Eager };

edgeOptions.AddArgument("headless");
edgeOptions.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
edgeOptions.AddArgument("enable-javascript");
edgeOptions.AddArgument("inprivate");
edgeOptions.AddArgument("whitelisted-ips=\"\"");

Driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeDriverService, edgeOptions, timeSpan);

Driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().AsynchronousJavaScript.Add(timeSpan);
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait.Add(timeSpan);
Driver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(timeSpan);
```

I want to like the method or extension like following

```
var result=await Driver.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync<T>(script,args)
(or)
var result=await Driver.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync<T>(script,waitTime,args)
```

So that I can use it in the future.

For more reference my backend is blazor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-async you have to "return" the data.

```
return ScreenToBase64()
```

For async arguments[0] (or higher if you pass variables) should be the resolver so you want to:

```
ScreenToBase64().then(arguments[0])
```